# Does gRPC nginx ingress require TLS always to work?

Tags: ssl, annotations, grpc, ingress-nginx

Example given in nginx-ingress for GRPC does not work without TLS in .NET client

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/grpc/

Please help me to configure without TLS

Created .NET console app as GRPC client and trying to connect ingress-NGINX for GRPC traffic

Comment: Please be more specific about "does not work". What problems are you seeing exactly?

Comment: yes. I had used TLS